# Adding Lodash to a new Rails 5.2 app with webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, lodash, webpacker

So, using Rails 5.2beta (`gem install rails --pre`), if you create a new app via `rails new myapp --webpack=react`... how would I go about incorporating Lodash into my flow from there?

I've mucked around with [babel-plugin-lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-lodash) and [lodash-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-webpack-plugin) to no avail.

The compile doesn't fail if I do something like `import { _pick, _map } from 'lodash/array';` ... but those variables are undefined when trying to use them.

I'm a bit lost as I'm both new to webpacker & webpack, and a lot of existing examples seem to target an older version of webpack?

Anyway, thank you for any help...

UPDATE:

Ok, looks like you can just do `import map from "lodash/map"`

Answer (score 0):

So where are you trying to use lodash from? By this I mean are you sure the files are getting compiled / processed by Webpacker, or are they getting processed via the Asset Pipeline?

On [my webpacker project](https://github.com/WilcoxDevelopmentSolutions/odyssey) I realized that there's a problem: that yes, regular old Javascript compiled with the Asset Pipeline won't know about the NPM Modules included via Webpack. (or at least the `require` statements wouldn't work).

Because of this I made a hard rule: all javascript goes where webpacker expect it (`app/javascript`) and **no** Javascript goes in `app/assets`. We only use the asset pipeline for CSS (which works great in our case, as I still don't think React - our frontend framework of choice - has a good story around site wide CSS).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'd prefer to use a webpack plugin, which could give me things like cherry-picked lodash functions, instead of simply doing something like  `import _ from ./lodash.core.js` (what I'm doing now)... but it's not a huge deal ultimately.